# Formula for When a Field Value is Null after Record Insertion

Tags: workflow, formula

Is it possible to write a formula for if a Date field is not null upon record insertion?

I would prefer to not write a trigger for this.

**Flow:**

Record Example A --> Field XYZ is `null` --> Formula evaluates to False.

Record Example B --> Field XYZ is `2016-04-25` --> Formula evaluates to True.

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you just need to negate the results of the `ISBLANK` function. You can also detect insert with `ISNEW`.

```
AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISBLANK(My_Date_Field__c)))
```